# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

[i hope this image help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TokvJ.png)  
[as well this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyvPl.png)

when i try to use provider to call async function from another file I get the error.
i dont know that it's a problem in the methode where i call it or in the file that i created the function. at the end i will say thank you because stack overflow says  add more details.

the code from pictures

```
void _saveForm() async {
var isValid = _form.currentState?.validate() as bool;
if (!isValid) {
  return;
}
_form.currentState?.save();
print(_editedProduct);
if (_editedProduct.id == '') {
  print('done');
  // ignore: await_only_futures
  await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
      .addProduct(_editedProduct); // this is where i get the error.
} else {
  Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
      .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
}
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

}

```
Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
var httpsUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'scheme',
  host: 'host',
  path: 'path',
);
final uri = Uri.parse(
    'host');

try {
  var res = await http.post(uri,
      body: json.encode({
        'title': product.title,
        'description': product.description,
        'price': product.price,
        'isFav': product.isFavorite,
        'imageUrl': product.imageUrl
      }));

  final newProduct = Product(
    title: product.title,
    description: product.description,
    price: product.price,
    imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
  );
  _items.add(newProduct);
  notifyListeners();
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

// _items.insert(0, newProduct); // at the start of the list
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {...}` means the function doesn't return anything but `Provider` needs a value so it throws an error.

Comment: even if i add a return type i get the same error like this        Future<bool> addProduct(Product product) async {

Comment: Then it probably means there should be a return statement in the function `addProduct()`.

Comment: it was vsc problem i just restarted it and it disappear it was unable detect changes i think.